# Unity not putting sprite in right place

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

So in this game when the player picks up items from the scene I'm trying to have it draw the item in their inventory. The problem is whenever the player picks up an item the sprite is drawn in the wrong area. I'm calling additem from itemid class and sending it to the inventory class. when it is sent the id goes with it and that's how it knows which item to draw. I'm trying to draw it in the next empty slot in the inventory. **in the inventory class if I comment in those AddItem(0) (or any number that has an item with it) it draws the sprite in the right location.** any ideas on why it is drawing the sprite in the wrong location when it is called from the itemid class

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {

ItemDataBase database;
GameObject inventoryPanel;
GameObject slotPanel;
public GameObject inventorySlot;
public GameObject inventoryItem;
int slotAmount;
public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
public List<GameObject> slots = new List<GameObject>();

 void Start()
{

    database = GetComponent<ItemDataBase>();

    slotAmount = 20;
    inventoryPanel = GameObject.Find("Inventory Panel");
    slotPanel = inventoryPanel.transform.FindChild("Slot Panel").gameObject;
    for (int i = 0; i < slotAmount; i++)
    {
        items.Add(new Item());
        // and empty slot
        slots.Add(Instantiate(inventorySlot));
        slots[i].GetComponent<Slot>().id = i;
        //set parent to slot panel
        slots[i].transform.SetParent(slotPanel.transform);
    }


   // AddItem(0);
   // AddItem(1);
   // AddItem(1);
   // AddItem(1);
   // Debug.Log(items[1].Title);
    inventoryPanel.SetActive(false);
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("i") && inventoryPanel.activeSelf == false)
    {
        inventoryPanel.SetActive(true);
    }
   else if(Input.GetKeyDown("i") && inventoryPanel.activeSelf == true)
      {
        inventoryPanel.SetActive(false);
    }
}

public void AddItem(int id)
{

    inventoryPanel.SetActive(true);
    Item itemToAdd = database.FetchItemByID(id);

    if (itemToAdd.Stackable && checkIfItemIsInInventory(itemToAdd))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].ID == id)
            {
                ItemData data = slots[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<ItemData>();
                data.amount++;
                data.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = data.amount.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            // in video had this set to -1
            if (items[i].ID == -1)
            {
                items[i] = itemToAdd;
                GameObject itemObj = Instantiate(inventoryItem);
                itemObj.GetComponent<ItemData>().item=itemToAdd;
                itemObj.GetComponent<ItemData>().amount = 1;
                itemObj.GetComponent<ItemData>().slot = i; 
                itemObj.transform.SetParent(slots[i].transform);
                itemObj.transform.position = Vector2.zero;
                itemObj.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = itemToAdd.Sprite;
                itemObj.name = itemToAdd.Title;
                itemObj.name = itemToAdd.Title;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool checkIfItemIsInInventory(Item item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (items[i].ID == item.ID)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

void RemoveItem (int id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].ID == id)
            {
                items[i] = new Item();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    }

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemId : MonoBehaviour {

public int id;
public Inventory additem;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log(id);
        additem.AddItem(1);

        Destroy(gameObject);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: `gameObject.GetComponent<Inventory>().AddItem(id);`

in the items id script. I know the additem(id) part is commented out but its not supposed to be was just trying to figure out what part was throwing the error and its the `additem(id)` if I comment that out no error happens

Comment: Ok. Where is Inventory attached to? To the game object that is detected in Trigger?

Comment: Inventory is its own thing. Does it need to be connected to the player or the object that I want to put into the inventory? or is there a way to call inventory.

Comment: It is supposed to be attached to a GameObject. atleast, an empty GameObject if you want its Start or Update function to be called. Just to let you know, you don't have to ignore your last two questions. You can accept those answers if they solved your problem.

Comment: Why did you change your whole question + title ? Also why is your posted code the same as the one found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423027/sprites-not-showing-up-in-slots) but posted with a different question from a different user ? (If you need further help with your initial question, add and edit or comment. Otherwise start a new question)